# Removing top level field in json4s when nested field with similar name exists

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I would like to remove a top level field called "id" in a json structure, without removing *all* fields named "id", which happens when I run the following code:

```
scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

scala> import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

scala> val json = parse("""{ "id": "bep", "foo": { "id" : "bap" } }""")
json: org.json4s.JValue = JObject(List((id,JString(bep)), (foo,JObject(List((id,JString(bap)))))))

scala> json removeField {
     |   case ("id", v) => true
     |   case _ => false
     | }
res0: org.json4s.JValue = JObject(List((foo,JObject(List()))))
```

Any idea how I can avoid removing the inner "id" field?

Edit: unfortunately I do not have the ability to list all the possible top level objects the json contains or can contain.

Comment: Well, you could use this approach here and select all the id fields that are not the first so that they remain the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216069/scala-remove-field-from-json-files-in-the-nested-object-with-defined-name

Comment: @nmat Not sure I follow? That answer is about removing a nested field without touching the outer fields, which is fine. I want to remove a top-level field without touching other, possibly nested, fields.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `removeField` applies to the entire JSON tree.

This works only for the top-level:

```
val updated = json match {
  case JObject(l) => JObject(l.filter {
    case (name, _) => name != "id"
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216069/scala-remove-field-from-json-files-in-the-nested-object-with-defined-name) you could do something like this:

```
val transformedJson2 = json transform { 
  case JField("id", _) => JNothing
  case JField("foo", fields) => fields
}
```

It is definitely not ideal because you would have to specify all the `foo` elements with a sub element `id`

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the answer. The input json is dynamic though and I can not control all the fields it contains.

Answer (score -1):

To do this without the need to know the schema of other fields:

```
JObject(
  json.asInstanceOf[JObject].obj.filterNot(_._1 == "id")
)
```

JObject().obj is the flat list of fields that compose the object.

This doesn't seem possible staying within the json4s DSL though.